# Assign php variable value to javascript value but JS Variable seems undefined across scripts

Tags: javascript

I am wondering why I don't get an alert message with the javascript  code below. It seems that the variable xyz is not recognized/defined? I can't find the mistake... Thank you very much for your help!

**main.php**

```
<?php
...
$abc="http://www.path.de/image.jpg";
...
?>    

<script type="text/javascript">
            var xyz="<?= $abc ?>";
</script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.alert(xyz);
</script>
```

**No Alert message! Browser Output in source view:**

```
...
<script type="text/javascript">
        var yxz = "http://www.bla.de/asd.jpg";
</script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.alert(yxz);

        </script>
...
```

Comment: The browser doesn't know how you generated your JavaScript code so the PHP bit is irrelevant. You're probably defining `yxz` inside a block or function and calling it somewhere else out of scope.

Comment: The error must be somewhere else in your code, cause the output you are showing here is working.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<?php
$abc="http://www.path.de/image.jpg";
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
      var xyz="<?php print $abc; ?>";
</script>
```

And, please, remember to use json_encode() function to be sure, that you won't screw up the javascript:

[Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines)

Answer (score 0):

Simply try

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert(<?=$abc?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var xyz="<?= echo $abc ?>";
```